# How do I detect an instance of an object in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have an image containing several specific objects. I would like to detect the positions of those objects in this image. To do that I have some model images containing the objects I would like to detect. These images are well cropped around the object instance I want to detect.

Here is an example:

In this big image,

[image]

I would like to detect the object represented in this model image:

[image]

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to take your question seriously. Write a proper title. Explain your problem specifically. **At the very least, use the right tags.** It's not that difficult. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tom: Explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Title: Identifying Objects in an Image in `MATLAB` and the tags are [C#], [javascript] and [c++]. so which one is it ?!   you are a new user so I won't -1...

Comment: modeling, texturing and lighting is good in the image. good work. mostly mental ray has been used for rendering...and for the question, god knows.

Comment: Well, at least say what have you tried so far, or if you don't know even how to start.

Comment: How can I reopen this question?? I was about to post my answer, when it was closed....

Comment: @Oli See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close on the FAQ about closed questions. "Closed questions cannot be answered, but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through editing, voting, and commenting." So if the question were edited and improved then it may be reopened.

Comment: @Oli Can you make a suggested edit that could bring this question up to a better standard of quality? I realize that the OP might just not realize how to articulate the question, you may be able to help. If you can get it in shape, I'd be happy to re-open it.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the question. But I don't have enough points to re-open it. The question was fine I think, the main problem was that there was the wrong tags....

Answer (score 38):

Since you [originally posted this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8591515/1) as a 'gimme-da-codez' question, showing absolutely no effort, I'm **not** going to give you the code. I will describe the approach in general terms, with hints along the way and it's up to you to figure out the exact code to do it.

Firstly, if you have a template, a larger image, and you want to find instances of that template in the image, **always think of [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation)**. The theory is the same whether you're processing 1D signals (called a matched filter in signal processing) or 2D images.

- Cross-correlating an image with a known template gives you a peak wherever the template is an exact match. Look up the function [`normxcorr2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/normxcorr2.html) and understand the example in the documentation.
- Once you find the peak, you'll have to account for the offset from the actual location in the original image. The offset is related to the fact that cross-correlating an `N` point signal with an `M` point signal results in an `N + M -1` point output. This should be clear once you read up on cross-correlation, but you should also look at the example in the doc I mentioned above to get an idea.

Once you do these two, then the rest is trivial and just involves cosmetic dressing up of your result. Here's my result after detecting the object following the above.

[image]

Here's a few code hints to get you going. Fill in the rest wherever I have `...`

```
%#read & convert the image
imgCol  = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbnV9.jpg');
imgGray = rgb2gray(img);
obj     = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYii.jpg'));

%# cross-correlate and find the offset
corr           = normxcorr2(...); 
[~,indx]       = max(abs(corr(:))); %# Modify for multiple instances (generalize)
[yPeak, xPeak] = ind2sub(...);
corrOffset     = [yPeak - ..., xPeak - ...]; 

%# create a mask
mask      = zeros(size(...));
mask(...) = 1;
mask      = imdilate(mask,ones(size(...)));

%# plot the above result
h1 = imshow(imgGray);
set(h1,'AlphaData',0.4)
hold on
h2 = imshow(imgCol);
set(h2,'AlphaData',mask)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you use `abs()`? A negative correlation is a good candidate?

Comment: @cyborg A correlation of -1 implies a signal that's exactly 180º out of phase with the original and as such, I'd consider it to be the same signal. Perhaps it's not necessary here, but I tend to use `abs`.

Comment: please could you tell what to enter values for creating a mask

Answer (score 9):

Here is the answer that I was about to post when the question was closed. I guess it's similar to yoda's answer.

You can try to use normalized cross corelation:

```
im=rgb2gray(imread('di-5Y01.jpg'));
imObj=rgb2gray(imread('di-FNMJ.jpg'));
score = normxcorr2(imObj,im);
imagesc(score)
```

The result is: (As you can see, the whitest point corresponds to the position of your object.)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Mathworks has a classic demo of image registration using the same technique as in @yoda's answer:

[Registering an Image Using Normalized Cross-Correlation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html)

Comment: @yoda, is it you? I don't pretend and don't want this answer to be accepted, but though it will be a useful information for OP and future readers.