# How to compare a picture in Appium, using Python code?

Tags: python, ios, appium

I need to compare template picture in iOS app. What syntax I need to use for it? I found so many information about it, but only with Java syntax.

I use Appium + Python on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you already retrieved the template image and the real image (to check against the template) by using the `get_screenshot_as_base64()` ([here](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/screenshot/) the documentation).

Then you can try to use the OpenCV library embedded inside Appium to check how similar the two images are by calling the function `get_images_similarity()` ([here](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/d679ed8aba7feeb27eede3886ee493595c615c67/appium/webdriver/extensions/images_comparison.py) the implementation) to get the similarity score of the two images and make reasoning on top of it.

For more detailed information have a look at [this](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/writing-running-appium/image-comparison/) useful article!

Comment: I learning the article you've mentioned. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use openCV library.
Because I cannot install opencv4nodejs
You can try to install it like this way, with npm module: `npm i -g opencv4nodejs`
So, I found solution to compare images. You can use this code:

```
/**
 * Finds the a region in one image that best matches another, smaller, image.
 */
public static int[] findSubImage(BufferedImage im1, BufferedImage im2){
    int w1 = im1.getWidth(); int h1 = im1.getHeight();
    int w2 = im2.getWidth(); int h2 = im2.getHeight();
    assert(w2 <= w1 && h2 <= h1);
    // will keep track of best position found
    int bestX = 0; int bestY = 0; double lowestDiff = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    // brute-force search through whole image (slow...)
    for(int x = 0;x < w1-w2;x++){
        for(int y = 0;y < h1-h2;y++){
            double comp = compareImages(im1.getSubimage(x,y,w2,h2),im2);
            if(comp < lowestDiff){
                bestX = x; bestY = y; lowestDiff = comp;
            }
        }
    }
    // output similarity measure from 0 to 1, with 0 being identical
    System.out.println(lowestDiff + "output similarity measure from 0 to 1, with 0 being identical");
    Assertions.assertTrue(lowestDiff<0.5);
    // return best location
    return new int[]{bestX,bestY};
}

/**
 * Determines how different two identically sized regions are.
 */
public static double compareImages(BufferedImage im1, BufferedImage im2){
    assert(im1.getHeight() == im2.getHeight() && im1.getWidth() == im2.getWidth());
    double variation = 0.0;
    for(int x = 0;x < im1.getWidth();x++){
        for(int y = 0;y < im1.getHeight();y++){
            variation += compareARGB(im1.getRGB(x,y),im2.getRGB(x,y))/Math.sqrt(3);
        }
    }
    return variation/(im1.getWidth()*im1.getHeight());
}

/**
 * Calculates the difference between two ARGB colours (BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB).
 */
public static double compareARGB(int rgb1, int rgb2){
    double r1 = ((rgb1 >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0; double r2 = ((rgb2 >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0;
    double g1 = ((rgb1 >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0;  double g2 = ((rgb2 >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0;
    double b1 = (rgb1 & 0xFF)/255.0;         double b2 = (rgb2 & 0xFF)/255.0;
    double a1 = ((rgb1 >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0; double a2 = ((rgb2 >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0;
    // if there is transparency, the alpha values will make difference smaller
    return a1*a2*Math.sqrt((r1-r2)*(r1-r2) + (g1-g2)*(g1-g2) + (b1-b2)*(b1-b2));
}
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598818/finding-a-picture-in-a-picture-with-java).
It works good, but too slow.
If you also cannot use openCV, you can use this way.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare pictures with template by OpenCV library. That's what I do:

1. Add method to `base_page.py`.

   ```
    def compare_image_with_screenshot(self, image_name: str):
    os.chdir('../src/screenshots/')

    with open(f'{image_name}.png', 'rb') as img:
        first_image = base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode('ascii')
    second_image = base64.b64encode(self._driver.get_screenshot_as_png()).decode('ascii')

    return self._driver.get_images_similarity(first_image, second_image)
   ```
2. Use this method in Page Object file.

   ```
    @allure.step('Compare screenshot with template')
    def get_image_comparison_percents(self):
    """
    This method gets screenshot on device with template in repo. Comparison result is percentage of similarity. Test is OK if comparison more than 90%
    """
    result = self.compare_image_with_screenshot(OfflineLocators.offline_stub)
    return result.get('score')
   ```
3. Use step in necessary test.

   ```
   @allure.link(url='https://jira.myproject.tech/browse/TEST-1', name='TEST-1 - Offline stub')
   @allure.title('Offline stub')
   def test_offline_stub(appdriver):

   TourActions(appdriver).skip_tour()
   Navigation(appdriver).open_my_offline_page()

   assert Offline(appdriver).get_page_title_text() == 'Offline'
   assert Offline(appdriver).get_image_comparison_percents() > 0.9
   ```

In result of all of this I get some percentage of pictures similarity. It can be with that percentage what you need. For my tests it is OK.