# detect the position of an object in the image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, optimization, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the 2D correlation algorithm to detect the position of an object in the image, i don't want to use any built in function estimates 2d correlation.

Here is my code:

```
I=imread('image.tif');      % image is a black image contains white letters.
h=imread('template.tif');   %template is a small image taken from the original image, it contains one white letter.
I=double(I);
h=double(h);
[nrows ncolumns]=size(I);
[nrows2 ncolumns2]=size(h);
C=zeros(nrows,ncolumns);

for u=1:(nrows-nrows2+1)
   for v=1:(ncolumns-ncolumns2+1)
       for x=1:nrows2
           for y=1:ncolumns2
               C(u,v)=C(u,v)+(h(x,y)*I(u+x-1,v+y-1));
           end
       end
  end
end

[maxC,ind] = max(C(:));
[m,n] = ind2sub(size(C),ind)   % the index represents the position of the letter.

output_image=(3.55/4).*C./100000;
imshow(uint8(output_image));
```

I think it is working! but it is very slow.

How can i replace the following code by a better code to speed up the algorithm?

```
   for x=1:nrows2
       for y=1:ncolumns2
           C(u,v)=C(u,v)+(h(x,y)*I(u+x-1,v+y-1));
       end
   end
```

I am thinking that in every time i have the following two matrices

`h(1:nrows2,1:ncolumns2)` and `I(u:u+nrows2-1,v:v+ncolumns2-1)`

another question, are there any improvements?

thanks.

Comment: You said, an object. can you try it with different objects in same image and then different quality/type of images?

Comment: You said, an object. can you try it with different objects in same image and then different quality/type of images? I am not front of a machine now. But following link could give you some optimizing ideas. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591515/how-do-i-detect-an-instance-of-an-object-in-an-image) PS: it is not great posting from mobile. I really want delete the first comment.

Comment: the image is a simple black image contains white letters, and the template is a black small image contains one white letter, in the output image i found the max value at the letter in the template(i tried multiple templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you can, try to use matrix ops.  So try something like:

```
rowInds = (1:nrows2)-1;
colInds = (1:ncolumns2)-1;

temp = h.*I(u+rowInds,v+colInds);
C(u,v) = sum(temp(:));
```

Instead of:

```
for x=1:nrows2
    for y=1:ncolumns2
        C(u,v)=C(u,v)+(h(x,y)*I(u+x-1,v+y-1));
    end
end
```

Comment: My answer assumes you want to use nothing more than matrix ops and for-loops.  If you can use FFT's, or convolution functions, use those, as others have said below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many improvements. You don't need a for loop at all. Since you do not want to use matlab's `xcorr2` function, you can use `conv2`. See the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360297/matlab-how-to-find-out-if-a-matrix-is-in-another-martrix/12084000#12084000).

Answer (score 0):

How about determining the cross correlation in the Fourier domain, following the [cross-correlation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-CorrelationTheorem.html)? That should guarantee a dramatic speed increase.

Comment: thank you i already applied it in the frequency domain(which is more fast), but i wanted to make it in the spatial domain.